# PHP: Matrix from custom class

Tags: php, arrays, class, default

I have create a matrix of tiles. I added a new class, named Tiles, which has some member attributes, like x,y, pos, etc.

I have a function which initialize this array and return with it, but there I get error:

```
$matrix = array ( array ( new Tile));
```

Than the function get this `$matrix` as parameter, and do this:

```
$matrix[$i][$j]->x = ...
```

And here I get this warning:

**Warning: Creating default object from empty value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix you created is only 1x1 in size. Use this code to create a matrix of MxN size:

```
$matrix = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $M; $i++) {
  $matrix[$i] = array();
  for ($j = 0; $j < $N; $j++) {
    $matrix[$i][$j] = new Tile;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im C++ developer and really long time ago not used PHP.